# Problems with WebView2 on WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webview2

I have a problem in WebView2 WinFroms. Im using a proxy in WebView2. After some time of using WebView2 when i enter youtube i get a connection error. [Image which represents error on YouTube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbJLB.png).

After i clear cache it gets solved. But again after some time same error occurs again.[Image which represents that its getting solved after i clear cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpFQU.png).
Can anyone tell what can be the problem and how can i solve it?

I have tried to clear the cache and it got solved but after some time same error happens again.